# Android : preferencescreen right to left

Tags: android, xml, right-to-left

This is the xml file of PreferenceScreen
the PreferenceCategory appears RTL as I need, but L other compnents Appear LTR
How to make thim RTL ?

I tied to follow this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html) and I added android:supportsRtl="true" to the  element in my manifest file but nothing happened !

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end">

    <PreferenceScreen
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:title="@string/about_feedex">
            <intent
                android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
                android:targetPackage="com.arrafni.news"
                android:targetClass="com.arrafni.news.activity.AboutActivity"/>
    </PreferenceScreen>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:title="@string/settings_category_refresh">

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="refresh.enabled"
            android:summary="@string/settings_refresh_enabled_description"
            android:title="@string/settings_refresh_enabled" />

        <ListPreference
            android:name="@string/settings_refresh_interval"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:defaultValue="1800000"
            android:dependency="refresh.enabled"
            android:entries="@array/settings_intervals"
            android:entryValues="@array/settings_interval_values"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:key="refresh.interval"
            android:summary="@string/settings_refresh_interval_description"
            android:title="@string/settings_refresh_interval" />

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="refreshonopen.enabled"
            android:summary="@string/settings_refresh_on_open_description"
            android:title="@string/settings_refresh_on_open" />

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:key="refreshwifionly.enabled"
            android:summary="@string/settings_refresh_wifi_only_description"
            android:title="@string/settings_refresh_wifi_only" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:title="@string/settings_category_content_presentation">

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:disableDependentsState="true"
            android:key="lighttheme"
            android:summary="@string/settings_lighttheme_description"
            android:title="@string/settings_lighttheme" />

        <ListPreference
            android:name="@string/settings_keep_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:defaultValue="4"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:entries="@array/settings_keep_times"
            android:entryValues="@array/settings_keep_time_values"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:key="keeptime"
            android:summary="@string/settings_keep_time_description"
            android:title="@string/settings_keep_time" />

        <ListPreference
            android:name="@string/settings_font_size"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:defaultValue="0"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:entries="@array/settings_font_sizes"
            android:entryValues="@array/settings_font_size_values"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:key="fontsize"
            android:summary="@string/settings_font_size_description"
            android:title="@string/settings_font_size" />

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:disableDependentsState="true"
            android:key="pictures.disable"
            android:summary="@string/settings_disable_pictures_description"
            android:title="@string/settings_disable_pictures" />

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:dependency="pictures.disable"
            android:key="pictures.fetch"
            android:summary="@string/settings_fetch_pictures_description"
            android:title="@string/settings_fetch_pictures" />

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:key="display_oldest_first"
            android:summary="@string/settings_display_oldest_first_description"
            android:title="@string/settings_display_oldest_first" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:title="@string/settings_category_notifications">

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:key="notifications.enabled"
            android:summary="@string/settings_notifications_enabled_description"
            android:title="@string/settings_notifications_enabled" />

        <RingtonePreference
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:dependency="notifications.enabled"
            android:key="notifications.ringtone"
            android:ringtoneType="notification"
            android:summary="@string/settings_notifications_ringtone_description"
            android:title="@string/settings_notifications_ringtone" />

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:dependency="notifications.enabled"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:key="notifications.vibrate"
            android:summary="@string/settings_notifications_vibrate_description"
            android:title="@string/settings_notifications_vibrate" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:textDirection = "rtl"
        android:title="@string/settings_category_network">

        <PreferenceScreen
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textDirection = "rtl"
            android:title="@string/settings_screen_proxy">

            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:textDirection = "rtl"
                android:key="proxy.enabled"
                android:title="@string/settings_proxy_enabled" />

            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:textDirection = "rtl"
                android:dependency="proxy.enabled"
                android:key="proxy.wifionly"
                android:summary="@string/settings_proxy_wifi_only_description"
                android:title="@string/settings_proxy_wifi_only" />

            <EditTextPreference
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:textDirection = "rtl"
                android:dependency="proxy.enabled"
                android:key="proxy.host"
                android:title="@string/settings_proxy_host" />

            <EditTextPreference
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:dependency="proxy.enabled"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:textDirection = "rtl"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:key="proxy.port"
                android:title="@string/settings_proxy_port" />

            <ListPreference
                android:name="@string/settings_proxy_type"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textDirection = "rtl"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:defaultValue="0"
                android:dependency="proxy.enabled"
                android:entries="@array/settings_proxy_types_names"
                android:entryValues="@array/settings_proxy_types"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:key="proxy.type"
                android:title="@string/settings_proxy_type" />
        </PreferenceScreen>
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you solved this?

There are 2 possible workarounds for this: extend each of the preferences, and add :

```
  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
  @Override
  protected View onCreateView(final ViewGroup paramViewGroup)
    {
    final View view=super.onCreateView(paramViewGroup);
    if(VERSION.SDK_INT>=VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
      view.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LOCALE);
    return view;
    }
```

another easier one is on the activity:

```
if(VERSION.SDK_INT>=VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
  getListView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LOCALE);
```

However, for both workarounds I can't find how to handle the dialogs being shown by pressing on some preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Customize CheckBoxPreference and EditTextPreference , ... to right direction:

```
public class EditTextPreferenceRTL extends EditTextPreference {

public EditTextPreferenceRTL(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(parent);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) ((LinearLayout) view).getChildAt(1);
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    return view;
}
}


public class CheckBoxPreferenceRTL extends CheckBoxPreference {

public CheckBoxPreferenceRTL(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = (LinearLayout)super.onCreateView(parent);
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) ((LinearLayout) view).getChildAt(1);
    ((LinearLayout)view).removeViewAt(1);
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    ((LinearLayout)view).addView(layout);
    return view;
}


}
```

Comment: What's about the input field on the dialog?